# MSBuild - Including References

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to learn MSBuild; and to begin I have a C# project file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>$(MSBuildProjectName)</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>$(MSBuildProjectName)</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <Csc 
      AdditionalLibPaths="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\" 
      References="@(Reference)"
      Sources="@(Compile)" 
      OutputAssembly="$(MSBuildProjectName).exe" 
      />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

However, CSC fails, saying it can't find the metadata file 'xyz', once for each reference that I've tried to include. Additionally, Visual Studio reports a similar problem:

[image: MSBuild References Problem]

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you getting this error because of the Target Name = "Build"

```
   <Target Name="Build">
      <Csc AdditionalLibPaths="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\"
      References="@(Reference)" 
      Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(MSBuildProjectName).exe" />
   </Target>
```

In particularly the line:

```
     <Csc AdditionalLibPaths="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\" 
      References="@(Reference)" 
      Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(MSBuildProjectName).exe" />
```

If you don't need you can remove this additional lib paths, if needed search on the web you should be able to fine how to set up the AddtionalLib paths. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/11/10/489666.aspx?Redirected=true) might assist you.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer. I'm not quite sure I get you; what are you suggesting I change?

Comment: It appears that you getting these errors because of <Csc AdditionalLibPaths . So if you remove them your errors should not appear.